# async methods: are there any concurrency issues the programmer must address

Tags: .net, concurrency, async

Let's say this  `getPhotoAsync` method can be invoked a few times a second, and that the responses from the remote server can take anywhere from half a second to thirty seconds, depending on the size of the payload. So there will be several concurrent requests pending. Does .NET keep track  "behind the scenes" of which response goes with which request? Is there any chance that `info` could be associated with the wrong response from the remote server?

```
public async Task<PhotoWithInfo> getPhotoAsync(object info, string photoid)
{
          //<snip> build url with photoid 

          var request = WebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(url));
          var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();   

          byte[] photo=null;

        // <snip> read the response stream and return a byte array
          photo =  myMemoryStream.ToArray();

          var  foo  = new PhotoWithInfo();
          foo.bytes = photo;
          foo.Info = info;           

          return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any chance that info could be associated with the wrong response from the remote server?

No.

When your `await` method is executed, the framework signs your Task onto the current thread as a continuation, and returns control of execution flow back to you.  So now you're holding a reference to that task.  When the async method returns, the framework will populate your Task with the correct value, or it will block when you interrogate the Task for its value if the async method hasn't returned yet.

Either way, you're holding the correct Task, so you'll get the correct value back.  `WebRequest` is an atomic class; it doesn't share state with other instances of `WebRequest`, and your usage of `WebRequest` here is local to the class and the Task.  Further, your `WebResponse` is tied to this specific `WebRequest` instance.  So no, there is no possibility of race conditions, because there is no shared state.

Comment: I read the question as asking if `GetResponseAsync` always returns a value related to the request that calls it, not if `await` runs the continuation for the `Task` being awaited.

Comment: Alright, but that doesn't have anything to do with `async` `await`.  The `request` object is local to this method, so it seems unlikely that other requests are commingled.

Comment: Correct; I read it as a red herring.  That was my reading of the question, granted, it's not completely clear what he's worried about.  I essentially read him as asking if `GetResponseAsync` has bugs, rather than if `await` has bugs, not that either seems particularly interesting as a question.

Comment: The continuation will always pick back up where it left off, but if the method is being called many times in rapid succession, there is no guarantee that the first Task to fire will be the first Task to complete.

Comment: @RubberDuck: How is that relevant here?  You can use `ContinueWith()` if you need them to execute in a certain sequence, but the Web Requests are still independent from each other.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's relevant because OP doesn't have a good grasp on the topic and the title of the question suggests a different question from the one that was presented. I sense confusion on OP's part and that bit of info is relevant for a full understanding. The task will always continue where it left off, but that doesn't totally eliminate race conditions.

Comment: @RubberDuck: OK, but why are we discussing something that is nonexistent in his code?  `WebRequest` doesn't even share cookies unless you hand it some saved ones.  See my update.

Comment: Thank you all. I am a database programmer mainly, where we have to worry about concurrency. My question here is really  "is there anything about this async web request that requires me, the programmer, to address the situation where multiple responses  are being returned not in the same sequence in which the requests were made, or is this all handled for me by the framework?"

Comment: Now that I understand it, I should have written in the comment above "My question here *was* really..."